# Problemas con Android Manifest : ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {montsemkd.eac1_activity/montsemkd.eac1_activity.Acitivty2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Estoy probando algo tan sencillo como pasar de una Activity a otra através de un botón.

```
Mi manifest es el siguiente:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="montsemkd.eac1_activity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Me ayudáis a entender que tengo que poner en el manifest para no tener problemas?

La clase principal es MainActivity con su interficie: activity_main.

Y la segunda pantalla es Activity2 con su interficie: pantalla2

muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola Montse, primeramente tu Activity se llama Acitivty2 y no Activity2. Por esa razón debes asegurarte de que este nombre de actividad se encuentre registrado en tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml. Como otra opción si es que se encuentra registrada como "Acitivty2" en tu AndroidManifest.xml, puedes renombrar la clase, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es problema que declares diferentes layout en cada Activity

> Me ayudáis a entender que tengo que poner en el manifest para no tener
>   problemas?
>
> La clase principal es MainActivity con su interficie: activity_main.
>
> Y la segunda pantalla es Activity2 con su interficie: pantalla2

Pero revisa el nombre, en realidad tu Activity se llama `Acitivty2` y no `Activity2`.

---

> ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {montsemkd.eac1_activity/montsemkd.eac1_activity.Acitivty2}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Debes declarar las Actividades que sean usadas en tu aplicación dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , en este caso debe declarar la activity de nombre `Acitivty2`

```
   <activity android:name=".Acitivty2"/>
```

dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="montsemkd.eac1_activity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity android:name=".Acitivty2"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Revisa el documento [**Declarar la actividad en el manifiesto**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities#Declaring)