# aplicación Android se cierra al intentar crear BD y tabla

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy aprendiendo kotlin, andoid y estoy desarrollando una aplicación que haga un pequeño crud, el cual me debe crear una base de datos y su tabla, una insercción de datos, un listado y actualización.

El problema lo tengo en que cuando llamo desde mi botón a mi clase que generaría la base de datos, tabla, etc... mi aplicación se cierra y no me devuelve el Toast que he creado para saber si lo estoy haciendo bien. Adjunto mi código de botón y mi clase Database.

creo que está devolviendo nullPointer, pero no se donde

Gracias por la ayuda.

**Class Database**

```
    package com.example.practicadesarrollo

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.widget.Toast

val DATABASE_NAME = "pacDesarrollo"
val NOMBRE_TABLA = "usuarios"
val COL_NOMBRE = "nombre"
val COL_APELLIDOS = "apellidos"
val COL_ID = "id"

class Database(var context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1){

    // función para crear la base de datos
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + NOMBRE_TABLA + " (" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_NOMBRE + " VARCHAR, " +
            COL_APELLIDOS + " VARCHAR;";

    if (db != null) {
        db.execSQL(createTable)

        if( createTable == null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ocurrió un error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Dato Insertado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

    // esta función se deja así
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


    // función para insertar en la BD
    fun insertData(user : User) {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        var cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_NOMBRE, user.nombre)
        cv.put(COL_APELLIDOS, user.apellidos)

        //insertamos
        var result = db.insert(NOMBRE_TABLA, null, cv)

        // comprobamos que se ha insertado bien

        if( result == -1.toLong())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ocurrió un error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Dato Insertado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

**Mi botón** (Está en otra activity)

```
btCrear.setOnClickListener({
        val intent = Intent(this, Database::class.java)
        var db = Database(context)
        var user = User("David", "Serrano")
        db.insertData(user)
        startActivity(intent)
    })
```

Como digo, ha hacer click en este botón, se me cierra la aplicación volviendome al activity1 que es mi menu principal, no se si lo ha hecho bien, si no... No me aparece el Toast

**Actualización** (Salida LogCat)

```
2020-11-19 10:25:12.761 21359-21359/? I/cticadesarroll: Not late-enabling -
Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-11-19 10:25:12.782 21359-21359/? I/cticadesarroll: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-11-19 10:25:12.784 21359-21359/? W/cticadesarroll: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-11-19 10:25:13.151 21359-21359/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-11-19 10:25:13.152 21359-21359/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-11-19 10:25:13.178 21359-21381/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-11-19 10:25:13.182 21359-21381/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-11-19 10:25:13.190 21359-21381/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-11-19 10:25:13.422 21359-21359/com.example.practicadesarrollo W/cticadesarroll: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-11-19 10:25:13.423 21359-21359/com.example.practicadesarrollo W/cticadesarroll: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-11-19 10:25:13.647 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeb2f6c60, tid 21379
2020-11-19 10:25:13.656 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-11-19 10:25:13.659 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-11-19 10:25:13.666 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb2f6090: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-11-19 10:25:13.685 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb2f6090: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xeb63ca30) (first time)
2020-11-19 10:25:13.709 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2020-11-19 10:25:13.709 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-11-19 10:25:13.710 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeb2f6790, tid 21379
2020-11-19 10:25:13.710 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2020-11-19 10:25:13.730 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fdd78000 size 0x2000
2020-11-19 10:25:13.736 21359-21379/com.example.practicadesarrollo D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
```

Acabo de ver mi problema:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.practicadesarrollo, PID: 22083
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.practicadesarrollo/com.example.practicadesarrollo.Database}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
    at com.example.practicadesarrollo.Activity2$onCreate$1.onClick(Activity2.kt:34)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: El mensaje en el LogCat que dice? nullPointer pero podrías especificar que más se muestra en el LogCat

Comment: No marca nada, ningún error nada... @Jorgesys yo inicio la activity 2, hago click en el boton para crear la base de datos y la tabla y se me cierra...

Comment: Si no muestra nada de información el LogCat eso si es demasiado raro :-| , de esta forma es más dificil saber que sucede, pueden ser diferentes causas.

Answer (score 0):

El Query para la creación de la tabla en SQLite de acuerdo a tu código es:

> "CREATE TABLE pacDesarrollo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
> nombre VARCHAR(256),
> apellidos VARCHAR(256)"

Debes tomar en cuenta estas consideraciones, al final agrega ";" y la longitud del varchar no es necesaria, realiza estos cambios en tu query:

```
val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + NOMBRE_TABLA + " (" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COL_NOMBRE + " VARCHAR, " +
                COL_APELLIDOS + " VARCHAR;";
```

No olvides eliminar la aplicación y volver a subirla, o eliminar los datos de la aplicación, esto para que se cree correctamente la estructura de la tabla.

---

Con respecto a el error:

> ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
> {com.example.practicadesarrollo/com.example.practicadesarrollo.Database};
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Ocurre cuando la Activity no esta registrada en el `AndroidManifest.xml`
Revisa:
[Problemas con Android Manifest : ActivityNotFoundException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198259/problemas-con-android-manifest/198261#198261)

Pero en este caso la clase Database no es una `Activity` por lo tanto no deberías iniciarla:

```
btCrear.setOnClickListener({
        //val intent = Intent(this, Database::class.java)
        var db = Database(context)
        var user = User("David", "Serrano")
        db.insertData(user)
       //* startActivity(intent)
    })
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y tus respuestas. he puesto mi tabla como dices, he ejecutado mi aplicación he mirado el LogCat y el resultado lo pongo en un update de mi pregunta... no estoy seguro lo que adjunto es correcto o no...

Comment: también he añadido el nuevo código de creación de mi tabla como tu comentaste... Gracias de nuevo

Comment: he añadido más cosas... he visto mi problema. Pero no entiendo muy bien, si yo tengo en mi activity 2 la llamada de los botones donde creo la base de datos, hago las insercciones, los update, etc... porque me dice que tengo que definirlo en main...

Comment: Que bien que puedes ver el LogCat, con respecto a el error la clase Database No es una Activity por lo tanto no debes iniciarla usando: startActivity(intent)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Y como se instancia una clase de kotlin??

Comment: De hecho es tal y como lo realizas    var db = Database(context) @scorpions

Comment: De verdad, muchas gracias, no sabes cuanto te agradezco tu ayuda. Y si quisiera crear la tabla usuarios cuando le de al botón de crear y no en el método onCreate, que estoy probando y puedo llamarlo pero necesito enviarlo un onjeto de tipo SQLiteDatabase. Es decir la acción del botón crear, debe crear una tabla en mi base de datos. Pero por lo que estoy viendo de serie hay que crear una tabla en el método onCreate, no¿?? Gracias de nuevo